# Ruby on Rails How to build a Payment model to deal with Paypal REST SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'd like to create a Payment model along the official [Paypal Example on Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal.rb).
But I'm stuck in the creating of the model with the desired fields.

```
Payment.new({
    :intent => "sale",
    :payer =>  {
        :payment_method =>  "paypal" },
    :redirect_urls => {
        :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/payment/execute",
        :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000/" },
    :transactions =>  [{
        :item_list => {
          :items => [{
            :name => "item",
            :sku => "item",
            :price => "5",
            :currency => "USD",
            :quantity => 1 }]},
        :amount =>  {
          :total =>  "5",
          :currency =>  "USD" },
    :description => "This is the payment transaction description." }]})
```

Starting with `rails g model Payment intent:string` ... I don't know how to create the nested fields like

```
:redirect_urls => {
    :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/payment/execute",
    :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000/" }
```

and more deeper

```
:transactions =>  [{
    :item_list => {
      :items => [{
        :name => "item",
        :sku => "item",
        :price => "5",
        :currency => "USD",
        :quantity => 1 }]},
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do yo want to create a model?

Comment: good question, I'll try to create only an object :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to do this for you. It will be something like this :

```
paypal_hash = {
    :intent => "sale",
    :payer =>  {
        :payment_method =>  "paypal" },
    :redirect_urls => {
        :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/payment/execute",
        :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000/" },
    :transactions =>  [{
        :item_list => {
          :items => [{
            :name => "item",
            :sku => "item",
            :price => "5",
            :currency => "USD",
            :quantity => 1 }]},
        :amount =>  {
          :total =>  "5",
          :currency =>  "USD" },
    :description => "This is the payment transaction description." }]}

paypal_obj = OpenStruct.new(paypal_hash)
paypal_obj.intent
# => "sales"
```

Comment: Awsome! ✨ Thanks a lot Jeremie!!

Comment: Note that `OpenStruct` will not convert the nested hashes, so `paypal_obj.redirect_urls.return_url` for example will not work. The `Hashie` gem implements a class called `Hashie::Mash` that will automatically convert the nested hashes too. Alternatively you can use this method from my personal extensions library: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/shenanigans/1.0.4/Hash%3Ato_ostruct